# email me when a charger is connected?

Tags: sms, email, calls, charging, alarm

I want to be able to leave a device with charger plugged in the socket, and have it email me (or call/text me on my another device) as soon as it gets power (ie when the charger is *technically*  or *officially* plugged in)

Scenario: I plug the device and leave it. There's no power. Power comes, the device emails/calls me.

Comment: You can try apps like tasker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), you could try this:

- **Condition:** State → Power
- **Task:** Send SMS

(Note that Compose Email / Compose MMS / Compose SMS only open the dialog and let you edit, so you would need to use the *Send SMS* option to have it automatically sent).